# How to set up different widths for the media breakpoints in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new to Bootstrap, so please bear with me. I am trying to set up my CSS for an internal web application I am creating. I have it working perfectly with a default bootstrap.css. However the default screen width are not what is needed as it will be used a lot of very high resolution monitors (as well as tables and possibly phones).

So what I am trying to do is compile my own bootstrap.css that has some new media break values in.

Current

```
xs = 480px
sm = 768px
md = 992px
lg = 1200px
```

What I want is

```
xs = 480px
sm = 992px
md = 1200px
lg = 1600px
```

or even better would be

```
xs = 480px
sm = 768px
md = 992px
lg = 1200px
xl = 1600px
```

However I cannot get this working. I enter the required values in the template, but the css it produces does not scale properly, it does not jump between the small and medium sizes properly.

[image: Bootstrap template]

Cheers Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this as well, and got the same results as you...

It seems like the "Customizer" did not update the two of the three media queries that handle the `container` widths correctly.

You should find these around line 695 in your custom file, after updating the values, it seems to work as expected...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/tRP9C/3/embedded/result/)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { /*Should be 992px*/
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { /*Should be 1200px*/
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .container {
    width: 1570px;
  }
}
```

I also logged this issue on github [See Here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12428). We will see what they say...

**Update:**

Looks like this was a known issue, and will be fixed with the 3.1 release. [See Here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11801)

Comment: Any idea when 3.1 will be released? In the meantime I will try what you suggest.

Comment: Now I just need to make the same change in the min version.

Comment: @MikeDymond I believe 3.1 was supposed to be released sometime this week, but I dont know if that will happen. Either way it should be in the very near future.

Comment: @MikeDymond 3.1 launched today!

Comment: Just tried to use the new version of Bootstrap to achieve what I want and it looks like it still has the same bug in the compiler! I certainly didn't look right to me. Can someone else please test it?

Comment: Scrap my last comment. Media breaks and container sizes are now in two separate areas of the config. Once I got that right it all seems to work fine.